# Passing in page specific content into a PHP included header

Tags: php, html, http-headers, title

I am creating a website for a local company and I am splitting off the header for each page into a individual php page which I then include into each page. I was wondering what would be the best practice to insert individual description and title content into the php header for each individual page. Should I create a php variable before the included header.php link and then insert that variable argument into the title and description tags in the php file? Each variable would have different titles and description depending on what page it's on. Or would it make more sense to someone include these different description and title content into another external php page? If you have a even more correct/easier way that would also work best with SEO please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a Metadata object definition, with all of the properties required (description, tags, etc). Then instantiate a Metadata object for each page of the site, just before including your header, and use the values of the current Metadata object in the header.

Comment: THanks Ryan, just started learning PHP a year or so ago and this helping me understand the object model of PHP a lot better. Do you know of a good site that explains the Object model in PHP pretty clearly? All the ones I come across online have pretty complex explanations.

Comment: Here's the best explanation possible from me: it's an object. What is an object? Well, let's say you have a car. That's an object, right?.. What color is the car? That's a variant (variable) of that object. $car = new Car(); $car->setColor('red')->setModel('Mustang')->setMaker('Ford'); My car's color is $car->getColor();. This guy is essentially having you do exactly that, but instead of a car you're dealing with your page.

Answer (score 1):

split your logic (and titles, page information, dynamic content) from your templates via an MVC type architecture

here are some easy to learn templating engines (and I believe the two most popular)

```
http://www.smarty.net
http://twig.sensiolabs.org
```

You can read about MVC architecture here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: Thanks for responding skrilled but this is a little too complicated for me. I'm still trying to grasp the basics of PHP.

Comment: It only sounds complicated because you are making it that way in your head. We have graphics designers that don't know a lick of php that develop our templates upstairs here at my office. If you can write a title tag, or even know what a variable is and can create a php page, you can use smarty. I think if you spent 5 minutes looking at documentation then you would realize it's simpler than you are pretending it is :p You really think this is complicated?: http://www.smarty.net/crash_course

Answer (score 0):

However you do it, basically what you suggest initially is one of the best ways. Define a variable, or object, or whatever, in each page before the inclusion of the header.php file (again, whether that's a template, or just a regular php inclusion, up to you). Then just set them to whatever you want for each page, and you're good to go.

Personally, I would recommend using a template engine like Smarty.

As for SEO, that's an entirely different conversation. That's more related to the content of the variables, as opposed to the implementation of them.